# Using vector as range in for-loop In Matlab

Tags: matlab

I was wondering what the rule is for using vectors as range in for-loop in Matlab?

For example,

```
range = [0.1:0.01:2]'; % wrong
range = [0.1:0.01:2]; % correct

for i = range
i
end
```

1. Why is it that if `range` is column vector, it will not work, while
   if `range` is row vector, it will?
2. Will `i = range` be interpreted as `i` taking each value of `range`,
   or `i` is assigned with vector `range`?

Thanks~

Answer (score 11):

More generally, `range` can be a matrix, and the loop variable loops over its columns.

```
range = rand(3,3);
for col = range
col
end

col =
      0.86341
      0.11625
      0.20319
col =
      0.59721
     0.098357
       0.8356
col =
      0.89578
      0.46217
      0.93585
```

So if `range` is a row vector, it will loop over its values. But if `range` is a column vector, it will loop over that single column as its value.

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/for.html:

> ```
> for index = values
>    program statements
>           :
> end
> ```
>
> ... `values` has one of the following forms:
>
> `valArray`
>
> creates a column vector index from subsequent columns of array
>   `valArray` on each iteration. For example, on the first iteration,
>   `index = valArray(:,1)`...

Answer (score 0):

1. It's that way because it's that way.  I don't think that there is any deep explanation for this.
2. As you would discover if you experimented, once you've made an assignment such as `range = [0.1:0.01:2]` then the variable called `range` is a row-vector comprising the values in the range.  Your loop will work just fine.  As it would if it started

   `for i = [0.1 0.11 0.12 ...]`